# How to publish and implement Ruby file to my website

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web

I'm a beginner of Ruby. I want to establish my website by programming with Ruby language.
Before that, I used to upload HTML files to my web-host server, so that I could update my website. But now I have no idea about what should I do with Ruby file.

Thank you!

Comment: I would try a rails tutorial or something along those lines. This is a very broad question.

Comment: @EliSadoff I'm using Brackets as IDE for programming with Ruby. And I just don't know what I'm suppose to do with finished project .

Comment: Is the finished product a regular ruby file? Is it an `erb` file? Does your host support server-side ruby compilation?

Comment: It's .rb file. And I'm using 000webhost as my serve r

Comment: Your IDE and file type are pretty meaningless. What framework (if any) are you using? Are you just using Net::HTTP? Are you just writing plain old Ruby and expecting it to run on a web server? There are **way** too many details here, and you seem to have some difficulty anticipating what they are. That's a good sign that the question is too broad. Stack Overflow is for asking and answering *specific programming questions.* You should read the [help file](http://stackoverflow.com/help) to figure out what subjects are and are not on topic.

Comment: @MarsAtomic ok, l guess I should change my question to "how to establish a website by using Ruby language?" I'm a novice in programming, I'm not familiar with some programming jargon. It's kind hard for me to demonstrate my question in English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the rails framework you may wanna try using cloud9 instead. Brackets from what i understand is "local". Whereas cloud9 is a "real" IDE. Additionally you can easily push your code to heroku where your code will be hosted at.

To get things started just head over to [cloud9](http://c9.io) to create an account to setup your IDE. If you are unfamiliar with it there are lots of guides out there that can help you to get things started.

However if you lack the fundamentals in using the rails framework, guides.rubyonrails.org may be a good place to start too.

Update:
There is no best language when it comes to developing a website. The fundamentals of a webpage are HTML/CSS.

HTML gives you the bones or structure, such as your titles and your paragraphs etc.

CSS gives you your styling, such as creating buttons or changing font color etc.

This 2 languages form the core part of what would be your website, at the very least on the front end (meaning to say what people see when they visit your website)

JavaScript is not a must but definitely a plus. It is able to improve the UI/UX (user interface/user experience) of your website.

Lastly would be your back-end language; what handles the processes that goes on behind the scenes. If you choose ruby (and by extension rails) then that is fine as well. Basically your back-end language will support your database and CRUD (create, read, update, delete) actions.

Comment: Thank you! I'll check that out. And I have one more question: what's the best language and IDE for website development?

Comment: I've updated the answer, at least anyone else that needs help would be able to see it there directly too. With regards to IDE, theres no best. C9 is good enough and its free. Good luck!